# NativeScript Angular - Charts Error - ChildNode is already parented by a ChartElement instance

Tags: angular, charts, nativescript

I can't seem to get a simple chart to appear using @nativescript/core version 7.0.0 and nativescript-ui-chart version 8.0.2. I get this error:

> System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
> System.err: Calling js method onCreateView failed
> System.err: Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ChildNode is already parented by a ChartElement instance.

This is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~10.1.0",
"@angular/common": "~10.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~10.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~10.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "~10.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.0",
"@angular/router": "~10.1.0",
"@nativescript/angular": "~10.1.0",
"@nativescript/core": "~7.0.0",
"@nativescript/theme": "~2.3.0",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.161",
"lodash": "^4.17.20",
"moment": "^2.28.0",
"nativescript-exit": "^1.0.1",
"nativescript-permissions": "^1.3.9",
"nativescript-sqlite": "^2.6.4",
"nativescript-ui-chart": "^8.0.2",
"nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^9.0.3",
"reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
"rxjs": "^6.6.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.1"
  },

"devDependencies": {
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.0",
"@nativescript/android": "7.0.0",
"@nativescript/types": "~7.0.0",
"@nativescript/webpack": "~3.0.0",
"@ngtools/webpack": "~10.1.0",
"typescript": "~3.9.0"
  },
```

I have imported the NativeScriptUIChartModule in my AppModule (I only have one module). This is my template:

```
<GridLayout rows="*" height="1000px">
    <RadCartesianChart row="0" style="font-size: 12;">
        <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries [items]="categoricalSource" categoryProperty="Country" valueProperty="Amount"></LineSeries>
        <CategoricalAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis></CategoricalAxis>
        <LinearAxis tkCartesianVerticalAxis></LinearAxis>
    </RadCartesianChart>
</GridLayout>
```

And this is the TS:

```
@Component({
selector: "category-spend",
templateUrl: "category-spend.component.html",
})

export class CategorySpendComponent {
categoricalSource: { Country: string, Amount: number, SecondVal: number, ThirdVal: number }[] = [
    { Country: "Germany", Amount: 15, SecondVal: 14, ThirdVal: 24 },
    { Country: "France", Amount: 13, SecondVal: 23, ThirdVal: 25 },
    { Country: "Bulgaria", Amount: 24, SecondVal: 17, ThirdVal: 23 },
    { Country: "Spain", Amount: 11, SecondVal: 19, ThirdVal: 24 },
    { Country: "USA", Amount: 18, SecondVal: 8, ThirdVal: 21 }
];

public constructor() {}
}
```

I have copied the above HTML and TS directly from a working NativeScript playground. The only difference I can think of is the versions are different. Here is the package.json of the working playground:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "8.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.14",
    "@nativescript/angular": "8.21.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "6.5.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "2.3.3",
    "@progress-nativechat/nativescript-nativechat": "3.0.0",
    "kinvey-nativescript-sdk": "4.2.5",
    "nativescript-accelerometer": "3.0.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "8.21.0",
    "nativescript-background-http": "4.2.1",
    "nativescript-camera": "4.5.0",
    "nativescript-image": "3.0.1",
    "nativescript-geolocation": "5.1.0",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "7.1.0",
    "nativescript-intl": "3.0.0",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "1.5.1",
    "nativescript-social-share": "1.6.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "1.0.6",
    "nativescript-ui-autocomplete": "6.0.1",
    "nativescript-ui-calendar": "6.1.0",
    "nativescript-ui-chart": "7.1.1",
    "nativescript-ui-dataform": "6.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-gauge": "6.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "8.0.1",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "8.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.5.4",
    "tns-core-modules": "6.5.0",
    "zone.js": "0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.14",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "8.3.24",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "1.5.1",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "6.5.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
}
```

Has anyone experienced this error with the latest version? How do I fix it? I really don't want to downgrade my whole app for this.